# customer/account/login Showpassword checkbox doesnt work

Tags: login, magento2.4.5

It works fine in registration page, but doesn't work for login of registered users

Answer (score 0):

when you are extended the login page , please ensure following codes exists for show password

```
<div class="field choice" data-bind="scope: 'showPassword'">
<!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
```

```
 {
    "*": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
            "components": {
                "showPassword": {
                    "component": "Magento_Customer/js/show-password",
                    "passwordSelector": "#pass"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: am not extending it, the code mentioned exists in the vendor files

Answer (score 0):

There is a change since Magento 2.4.3-p1, take a look at this commit
https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/c816799062831cff940e92c89a1de30432d3cfd2

So, you should make sure your custom code in your module/theme or 3rd-party extension/theme apply the changes from that commit:

Related files:

- `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/web/template/show-password.html`
- `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/web/js/show-password.js`

Comment: Both vendor files in my code have the same content as the commit

Comment: If you see any errors in Console tab of the Browser’s developer tool, please add it into your question.

Comment: no, there are no errors at all

Comment: Assume your locale on frontend is en_US, and you are using `Magento/luma` theme, edit `pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Magento_Customer/js/show-password.js` to add `console.log` before `this._showPassword(isChecked);` and before `$(this.passwordSelector).attr('type',`  to debugging. Remember to change locale code and theme path if needed.

Comment: "Both vendor files in my code have the same content as the commit" I mean your should check your custom code in your module/theme or 3rd-party extension/theme that overrides these files, not tell you to check the Magento code base in vendor.

Answer (score 0):

First override **vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/login.phtml** file to in your theme
and then change password input id **"pass" to "password"** on line no :40 on your theme login.phtml file also change in script **"passwordSelector": "#pass" to "passwordSelector": "#password"** then cache flush and check.

```
<input name="login[password]" type="password"
                            <?php if ($block->isAutocompleteDisabled()): ?> autocomplete="off"<?php endif; ?>
                               class="input-text" id="password"
                               title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Password')) ?>"
                               data-validate="{required:true}">
```

---

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "*": {
                "Magento_Customer/js/block-submit-on-send": {
                    "formId": "login-form"
                },
                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                    "components": {
                        "showPassword": {
                            "component": "Magento_Customer/js/show-password",
                            "passwordSelector": "#password"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```